# How do I upgrade from Ruby 1.8.6 to 1.8.7 in Ubuntu without using RVM?

Tags: ruby, ubuntu

How do I upgrade Ruby 1.8.6 to 1.8.7 without using RVM?

I want to use one version in the production server.

Comment: Compile from source?  Use ruby-build? https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a better fit for http://askubuntu.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like someone has done it for you already:

http://wiki.brightbox.co.uk/docs:ruby:1.8.7

What version of Ubuntu?